# CQRS pattern with Event Sourcing having single database for read/write

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have a single SQL Server database for both read and write operation, and I am implementing CQRS pattern for code segregation and maintainability so that I can assign read operations to few resources in my team and write operations to other, I see using CQRS seems to be a clean approach.

Now, whenever there are Inserts/Update/Deletes happening on tables in my database, I need to send messages to other systems who need to know about the changes in my system, as my database is master data so any changes happening here needs to be projected to down stream systems so that they get the latest data and maintain it in their systems. For this purpose I may use MQ or Kafka so whenever there is change i can generate key message and put in MQ or use kafka for messaging purpose.

Until now I haven't used Event Sourcing as I thought since I don't have multiple databases for read/write, so I might not need Event Sourcing, is my assumption right that if we have single database we don't need Event Sourcing ? or Event Sourcing can play any role in utilizing MQ or Kafka, I mean if i use Event Sourcing pattern i can save data first in the master database and use Event Sourcing pattern to write the changes into MQ or use kafka to write messages I am clueless here if we can use Event Sourcing pattern for MQ or Kafka.

Do I need Event Sourcing for writing message to MQ or for using Kafka ? or it's not need at all in my case as i have only one database and I don't need to know the series of updates that happened to the system of record and all i care is about the final state of the record in my master database and then use MQ or Kafka to send about changes to downstream systems where ever there are CRUD operations so that they will have the latest changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is my assumption right that if we have single database we don't need Event Sourcing ?

No, that assumption is wrong.

In the CQRS "tradition", *event sourcing* refers to maintaining information in a persistent data structure; when new information arrives, we *append* that information to what we already know.  In other words, it describes the pattern we use to remember information.  See [Fowler 2005](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html).

When you starting talking about messaging solutions like Kafka or Rabbit, you are in a different problem space: how do you *share* information between systems?  Well, we put the information into a message, and deliver that message from the producer to the consumer(s).  And for reasons of history, that message is called an Event (see Hohpe et al).

Two different ideas, easily confused.  When CQRS people talk about event sourcing, they don't mean the same thing as Kafka people talking about event sourcing.

> Do I need Event Sourcing for writing message to MQ or for using Kafka ?

No - messaging still works even when you choose other remembering strategies than event sourcing.

It's perfectly reasonable to modify your model "in place", as it were, and then to also publish a message announcing that things have changed.

> why do I need Event Sourcing when I have only one database and I don't care about the series of changes to the records but care only about the final state of the data,

You don't.

The two most common motivations for event sourcing is that either (a) an event history has natural alignment with the domain you are working in (for instance: accounting) or (b) a need to support temporal queries.

If you don't have those problems, then you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks, but why do I need Event Sourcing when I have only one database and I don't care about the series of changes to the records but care only about the final state of the data, but yes I might need to stream the changes as and when data change happen may be by using MQ or Kafka so that other down stream system capture the changes and update their database, now what role does Event Sourcing play here, do I really need Event Sourcing ?

Comment: Great answer. I would just add, that you don't need message bus at all. Actually I encourage you to avoid it.
Instead pushing events to consumers (propagating events to our query model), the consumers can pull new events from event store.